# Way to present a UIImagePicker inside a UIViewController in a PopOver

Tags: ipad, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to display a UIImagePickerController inside a UIViewController via PopOver.
  I have added a PopOver via :

```
overlayTableViewCtrl = [[OverlayTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *navCtrl=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:selectedPunchTableViewCtrl];
    popOverViewController= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navCtrl];

 [popOverViewController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

I am then adding a UIImagePickerController on a UIViewController via

```
[self presentViewController:cameraPickerCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have set a content size for my ViewCtrl :

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 400);
```

I see the camera inside my ViewCtrl by `cameraPickerCtrl.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;`
 
but it appears with a black overlay . I also added a cameraViewTransform but it doesn't help for a custom size of UIViewController taking UIScreen bounds for aspect ratio.

Have anyone tried with a UIImagePickerController inside a custom sized UIViewController in a navigationController hierarchy? Are there any good examples for adding on ipad without Storyboard